# Setting up a server that routes local traffic through vpn, while still being able to access internet directly

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

The goal is to setup a local server that routes local traffic through an uncontrolled remote vpn service while still being able to access the internet directly (not tunneled via vpn) and provide services through that direct connection.

It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Note: There is another router with modem between the local server and the internet.

What is the easiest (best?) way to get this network setup working?

I'm planning to setup the connection between the local router and the local server with simple ip forwarding.

The problem now is that all the server's traffic is routed through the vpn tunnel as soon as I connect the server's openvpn client to the remote service so there is no direct internet connection available.
My first idea was to setup a virtual machine (lxc container or something) and run the vpn client and local networking stuff in the vm. So that the vm receives all the incoming traffic from the local router and tunnels it through the vpn. This, as far as I understand, should not affect the physical server's network connection and should allow it to provide services to the internet.
Before I start trying to set this up (I don't have much experience in networking), is there any easier or better way to do this? I would be thankful for every suggestion.

Edit: Let's say the interface connected to the internet is eth0 and the interface connected to the local router is eth1.
Another idea would be to create a virtual interface eth0:0 and specifiy it as openvpn's local endpoint and then force any traffic coming from eth1 through eth0:0. I'm not sure how I would force the traffic through eth0:0, though (possibly by adding routes).

Comment: Did you solve this issue?  I'm attempting something similar using a Linux server and client.  I want the client to access the intenret directly, but on the SSH port, I want to use a VPN connection to a publicly available sever and keep the connection secure using pre-shared keys for VPN encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the routing table on the server.

You don't say if it's a linux or windows server, but your mention of lxc suggests linux.

Use the netstat command to list your routing table (command: 'netstat -r' works on almost every operating system)

You will probably see that there is a default route (to 0.0.0.0/0) to push all traffic through the VPN provider that is added by the vpn software when it starts. You can remove this route and add your own to only push selected traffic through the VPN using the route command (route add and route delete).